# countdown UILabel not get decremented

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am trying to make a count down label,
But it is not getting decremented..Can any one spot out the error in code

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self   selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void) updateCountdown
{
     int hours, minutes, seconds;
     int secondsLeft = 30;
     hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
     minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
     seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
     countDownlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

Comment: becauseeeeeee you are taking secondsleft as static value so how it will update your countdownlabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem...

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender{


countDownView.hidden=NO;

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateElapsedTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
secondsLeft=30;

}



 -(void) updateCountdown {
int hours, minutes, seconds;


hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
countDownlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because each time when timer fires you use same value for seconds
`int secondsLeft=30;`

You must set value for secondsLeft on starting Timer and decrement it on timer

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender{

  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self   selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

  secondsLeft=30;
 }

 -(void) updateCountdown {
    int hours, minutes, seconds;

    secondsLeft--;
    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
    countDownlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare `secondsLeft` and `timer` as ivars, decrement `secondsLeft` every time `updateCountdown` is called and invalidate the `timer` when there are no seconds left to decrement.

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    secondsLeft = 30;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self   selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
}

- (void) updateCountdown
{
    int hours, minutes, seconds;

    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
    countDownlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
    secondsLeft--;

    if (seconds==0)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned `int secondsLeft=30;` in your `updateCountdown` method that's normal.

You should set the initial value of secondLeft somewhere else and then in your method `updateCountdown` you need to decrement it's value

```
 -(void) updateCountdown {
    int hours, minutes, seconds;

    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
    countDownlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
    if (secondsLeft > 0) secondsLeft--;
}
```